# SQL Wildcard search issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, wildcard

This is the question in 'Hackerrank'

> "Query the list of CITY(Column) names from STATION(Table) that do not
>   start with vowels and do not end with vowels. Your result cannot
>   contain duplicates."

Below is my answer, but I am getting an error in Hackerrank. Am I missing something that is very silly?

```
SELECT DISTINCT [City] FROM [Station] WHERE [City] NOT LIKE '[aeiou]%[aeiou]'
```

Comment: "Dubai" ends with a vowel, but would appear in your results, is it is `NOT LIKE '[aeiou]%[aeiou]'`

Comment: @MattGibson But the question says about city starts with a vowel and ends with a vowel, there is an 'and' condition, right?

Comment: The requirement is ambiguous. Are they wanting to exclude `Atlanta` because it both starts and ends with a vowel as you interpreted, or do they want to exclude all that either start with `Austin` or end with `Nashville` a vowel including those that do both `Atlanta`?  Perhaps the meaning is the 2nd form where none of the 3 names listed should be present.

Answer (score 0):

Just break it up...

```
[City] NOT LIKE '[aeiou]%' AND [City] NOT LIKE '%[aeiou]'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say take off start and end closing brackets aswel

```
[City] NOT LIKE 'aeiou%' AND [City] NOT LIKE '%aeiou'
```

Comment: That is incorrect. The brackets denote any of the characters listed or in a range. Your query is excluding words that literally start with or end with `aeiou` instead of any one of the letters.

Comment: If he wants to get in range , brackets should be included. You right. i assumed that's letters he do not want

Comment: OP stated "that do not start with vowels" thus start = single letter.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
SELECT
  distinct (city)
FROM
  station
WHERE
  city not rlike '^[aeiouAEIOU].* $'
  AND city not rlike '^.* [aeiouAEIOU]$';
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove space from above query, this will work perfectly

```
SELECT
  distinct (city)
FROM
  station
WHERE
  city not rlike '^[aeiouAEIOU].*$'
  AND city not rlike '^.*[aeiouAEIOU]$';
```

Comment: The syntax of your query is very different to the OP, which makes it very difficult to work out which  "space" you mean. Please redraft your answer to line up with the OP, and also format the SQL as code.